# CSS class is missed after jQuery replaceWith. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, .net

I added this line to a master.cs page.

```
<h4 class="hideAndShow">[ - ] Hide</h4>
```

In CSS file:

```
.hideAndShow
{
    position: fixed;
    top:120px;
    right:420px;
    color: white;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Then this  in the same master.cs page.

```
        <script>
            var hideShowBool = true;

            $('.hideAndShow').bind('click', function ()
            {
                if (hideShowBool == true)
                {
                    $(this).replaceWith('<h4 class="hideAndShow">[ + ] Show</h4>');
                    hideShowBool = false;
                } else
                {
                    $(this).replaceWith('<h4 class="hideAndShow">[ - ] Hide</h4>');
                    hideShowBool = true;
                }
            });
        </script>
```

The expected behavior:
The text **[ - ] Hide** should toggle between:  **[ + ] Show** and **[ - ] Hide**.

But what happens is that it only responds to the very first click. In that **[ - ] Hide** is replaced with **[ + ] Show**. But when clicking it again; there is no effect as expected.

Where is the problem? and How to fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fLmmu6sv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are replacing the element, so the new element doesn't have any click handler bound to it. You can either use the event delegation technique:

```
$('#aStaticParentElement').on('click', '.hideAndShow', function () {
```

Or change the text content of the element instead of replacing it:

```
$('.hideAndShow').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, currentText) {
        return currentText === '[ + ] Show'
               ? '[ - ] Hide'
               : '[ + ] Show';
    });
});
```